# How to achieve this material effect?

Tags: android, material-design

I have seen this in a lot of apps but I don't know what exactly this is called....
Can anyone tell me? I actually wanna show some text in my app with this raised background kind of thing....
Please tell me how to get this effect..

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya, I am asking about the background, not the line

Comment: Its looks like a [`CardView`](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView) with a shadow. Such an effect can of course be achieved without the `CardView`, but using it, by far, would be simpler. Additional reading: [`CardView` reference doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html). Specifically, [cardElevation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation)

Comment: @NitishDash See above comment .

Comment: I call it **9 patch**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="My Title Text"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#e6b121"
            android:id="@+id/your_id" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel esse eripuit patrioque id. Id inimicus scripserit delicatissimi est, id vide velit erant sed. Has an veri mutat accumsan, te iusto dolore similique nec. An laboramus delicatissimi nam, ea brute consul vis."
                android:id="@+id/textView17" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

which will give you as a result this:

[image]

and also try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="My Title Text"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#e6b121"
            android:id="@+id/your_id" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Screen On:"
                        android:id="@+id/textView17" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="19m 28s"
                        android:id="@+id/textView18" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Discharge while On/Off:"
                        android:id="@+id/textView19" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="7% / 3%"
                        android:id="@+id/textView20" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

But of course you are going to need to implement a custom adapter to adapt them into a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`

Hope it helps!!!